# How to create new binary file in cpp

Tags: c++

I am new in c++. I tried to create the binary file in c++. But not able to create it.Below is my source code.

```
void main()
{
 ofstream myfile;
 myfile.open("D:\get\data.bin",ios::binary);
 if (myfile.is_open()) 
 cout<<"hi"<<endl;
 else
     cout<<"bye"<<endl;
}
```

I always get bye output only.
My required target is to create a binary file in D directory with the data as a file name.I am using VS2010 and os is win 7.
 for providing the help

Comment: You'll want to replace cout in your code with myfile; if you want to write to the binary file that is.

Comment: [cpp simple binary file](http://www.codingunit.com/cplusplus-tutorial-file-io-in-cplusplus-text-and-binary-files) or [c++ text & binary prog](http://www.cppforschool.com/tutorial/files2.html) check these out.

Answer (score 8):

You have to double the backslashes :

```
"D:\\get\\data.bin"
```

Have a look at [escaped characters](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Escape_character).

Comment: Or use forward slashes `D:/get/data.bin`

Comment: Thank you.This worked for me.But why backward slashes does not work can u explain me please.Because some time when i  use "d:\test.bin" it works for me but not always i checked for spaces in the path it seems to be ok.

Comment: In fact, `\n`means *new line*, `\t` is *tab* for example. Specials chars like `\ or "` have to be [escaped](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Escape_character) `\\ and \"`